# jquery.min.js version conflict not working in asp.net website

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net application. Previously the application was using **jquery-1.7.2.min.js** version. But I had to upgrade it to **jquery-2.1.3.min.js** in order to make kendo charts work.

But now, a textbox with fieldType 'date' stopped popping up calendar with the new version.

Here is my textbox,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom" fieldtype='date' CssClass="selectstyle" Width="150px" runat="server" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>

$(function () {
        $('input[fieldtype="date"]').datepicker({ firstDay: 1
                                                , changeMonth: true
                                                , changeYear: true
        });
    });
```

Now the problem is, if I keep the old version of jQuery, kendo charts do not work and if I keep the new version of jQuery, above JavaScript fails.

Is there any way, I can update **jquery-2.1.3.min.js** to consider the above script for fieldtype?

Comment: make sure you also update jquery-ui, as datepicker is part of that

Comment: How can I do that? Do I download the latest jQuery UI?

Comment: You can add and update jQuery and jQueryUI packages using NuGet package manager in your ASP.NET project or you could reference the ones hosted by google: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` calendar control belongs to a different library called `jQuery-ui`. You need to upgrade it as well, the same way you upgraded the old jQuery library to a newer version. You can use [CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jqueryui) for that or just download the needed version directly from the [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/download/all/) website.

Remember, that versions doesn't have to be the same because they are two different libraries. I think `jQuery-ui-1.11.3.js` should work for you.

Comment: I added the following lines in my <head> tag, but it is still not working. <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: How do you include 'jquery-2.1.3.min.js' file? Post the actual code.

Comment: I have not included 'jquery-2.1.3.min.js' file for this particular page. And it is included in my jQuery folder in the solution.